# How to retrieve weblogic domain home?

Tags: java, weblogic-10.x

hi guys I want to retrieve the name and path of the domain of weblogic from my start up class. how can i achieve this?

Comment: What path are you looking for exactly?  The path to where the domain is staged on the managed server?

Comment: @steve: yeah i want the path to my domain example:C:\bea10.3\user_projects\domains\base_domain_103. base_domain_103 is my domain home

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't confirmed this, but you may be able to get at this information using an [Application Life Cycle Listener](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/programming/lifecycle.html).

An example [here](http://weblogic-wonders.com/weblogic/2009/12/04/creating-application-life-cycle-listener/).

You can get a `AppDeploymentMBea` from the `ApplicationContext` in the `ApplicationLifecycleEvent`.  `AppDeploymentMBea` has an `InstallDir`.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `getCurrentDirectory()` of ServerRuntimeMBean

Answer (score 0):

Java EE:
ServletContext with a Listener can use getRealPath("..."), *provided* you let your deployment be not as war (where there are no files), but for instance as unpacked war. Otherwise getRealPath would yield null. Try getRealPath.

Comment: I dont want to use the servlet context because i ll be using that class as a start up class..